# Load data s3 to MYSQL Aurora - not working using mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to execute the load on a temp table using `mysql.connector`.

The query is execute but when I check the temp table records using `cursors.fetchone()` it returns `None`.

The query itself is executed properly using SQL IDE.

How do I execute the load statements properly on a temp table in mysql using the python `mysql.connector`?

Comment: Could you please post the code you have written to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You chose not to show us how you're adding rows to a relation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html

It appears the OP describes this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo LIKE bar;
INSERT INTO foo SELECT * FROM bar;
COMMIT;
```

Notice the documentation explains that multiple
sessions can simultaneously create such a `foo` table,
and each session will have its own private instance,
inaccessible by other sessions.
In particular, inaccessible by a new python client session.

> two different sessions can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other